# Diagonalise and concatenate every row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

Given a matrix:

```
A = [1 2 3
     4 5 6
     7 8 9]
```

How to diagonalize each row of `A` and concatenate them simultaneously, so it yields the following?

```
1 0 0 4 0 0 7 0 0 
0 2 0 0 5 0 0 8 0
0 0 3 0 0 6 0 0 9
```

Comment: See the duplicate target. You just need to transpose at the end

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `diag(v)` function, and apply it to every row of A.

```
B = diag(A(1,:))
for i=2:size(A)
    B = [B,diag(A(i,:))]
end
```

Comment: Bad idea, appending matrices. You'll not notice anything with just a few matrices, but try doing this with 100,000 matrices. (Not to mention the use of `size` which is dangerous.

Comment: Do you have a better answer to the question or would like to elaborate on the dangers? The appending matrices criticism is to the question or the answer?

Comment: As I told you: try with 100,000 matrices and you'll see what the problem is. It'll take ridiculously long, as MATLAB has to create a new variable slightly larger than the old one, then copy the old to that, append the next in the created slots and delete the old matrix **each iteration**. Ergo: very, very, very slow. Which incidentally is why MATLAB puts orange wiggles with a warning underneath that line, it's not for making it look festive. For a better answer: look at the duplicate target.